# Do I need to specify text-align: center in a button CSS?

Tags: html, css

I see some of the frameworks doing this but it seems to me it is the default. Has anyone any experience with anything other than the default or do they know why it is specified?

Comment: Using such frameworks you can assign button classes not to `button` elements only, but other elements like `a`, `div` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most frameworks let you set their button classes not to button elements only, but other elements like `a`, `div`, `span` etc.

The below illustrates it by using bootstrap `btn` class name <sup>(**1**)</sup>

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/o01ebm5k/1/)

```css
.btn{ margin:5px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn btn-primary">This is a div</div><hr>
<a class="btn btn-success"> this is an anchor</a><hr>
<button class="btn btn-warning">Finally, a button</button>
```

---

<sup>(**1**)</sup> Same thing for [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/button.html)  `button` class and [Pure.css](http://purecss.io/buttons/) `pure-button` class.